# How to use http.Get request inside handler func

Tags: go

How to make http.Get request inside of handler func?
For example, this simple code "should" return blank page in localhost:8080 browser but it go nuts. What I have missed in school?

```
package main

import "net/http"

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, err := http.Get("www.google.com")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: First you should fix the syntax errors. Then if you still have trouble, post the program and the error you have received. See [mcve] for more information. I've voted to close, because this program works once the syntax errors are fixed.

Comment: You need to explain what "it go nuts" means. There's no reason you can't make an http request in a handler, so we need an example of what is actually happening.

Comment: Sorry for syntax errors.

Comment: I got this in cmd:2018/11/08 20:54:49 http: panic serving [::1]:62123: Get www.google.com: unsupported protocol scheme ""
goroutine 4 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0000de000)
        C:/GO/src/net/http/server.go:1746 +0xd7
panic(0x65c6a0, 0xc00005eea0)

Comment: It does not work on my machine. Error log is to long to be posted here so I have posted just severl lines of error log

Comment: `www.google.com` is not a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should use a *protocol* (e.g. `https://`) in the `Get` function:

```golang
_, err := http.Get("https://www.google.com")
```

The error in you original code is `Get www.google.com: unsupported protocol scheme ""`.

[image]

`http.Get()` expects a URL, and `www.google.com` is not a URL; a URL begins with a *scheme*.  Even though it is common to type "www.google.com" into a browser, it's still not a full URL; friendly browsers automatically prepend "http://" or "https://" before issuing the request.  `http.Get()` isn't going to do that; it expects a well-formed URL to begin with.

Comment: There's no reason for this to be a screenshot and not just text.